# Подключение к сайту на компьютере через роутер

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер, ip, маршрутизация, port

Есть сайт, есть сервер. На локальных адресах работает хорошо. Ноутбук подключен к компьютеру. Нужно, чтобы при запросе на IP роутера, то бишь на внешний IP, запросы посылались на мой ноут, чтоб сайт можно было открыть с любого устройства вне локальной сети.
Что есть:
Мой IP в локальной сети:
[image: IP address]
Проброс портов через роутер организовал:
[image: Порты]
В брандмауэре организовал правило входящего и исходящего подключений для порта `80`.
На node.js написал сам скрипт подключения (на локальных адресах он работает):

```js
const address = '192.168.1.65';
const port = 80;
// code code code ...
app.listen(port, address, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${address}:${port}`);
});
```

И в итоге, имею:
[image: Консольный вывод]

Итак. Не работает оно. По внешнему IP (его я беру с сайта 2ip.ru) запрос не доходит до ноута. То есть, например, по адресу `http://192.168.1.65:80` мой сайт открывается, по адресу `http://a.d.d.r:80` - нет.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если у вас такая же проблема, скорее всего проблемы с роутером. Например, не работает проброс портов. В моем случае роутер говорит, что его внешний IP адрес - один адрес, а по факту мой внешний IP - другой. То есть, в настройках роутера написан адрес `10.13.235.96`, а на сайте 2ip.ru - `78.107.205.23`. Как вы понимаете, никакой проброс тут не поможет